# DLC for PAYDAY 2 on PS3

Tags: ps3, payday-2

I have looked around at DLC for PAYDAY 2 and I am wondering if any of the DLC packs, like Deathwish, can be downloaded on a PS3. I have achieved a lot of the game on PS3 and I was hoping I could play these DLC packs on my PS3.

Answer (score 3):

None of the big [DLC packs](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/DLC_%28Payday_2%29), free or paid, for Payday 2 are available on console (360 or PS3) - they're currently Steam exclusive.

The word seems to be that consoles will get this content *eventually*, but I'm having a hard time finding anything solid from the developers about when (if ever) it will be released.

Comment: That sucks.I just recently got a beautiful gaming computer and I didn't want to have to buy the game again for PC just to start over with all those DLC packs.Thanks for the information.I'll keep an open eye for any new DLC packs for PS3 and 360.If needed,I'll buy it again for PC.

Comment: Some internet sources are reporting Payday 2 and the DLC will be rebundled for Xbox One/PS4.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can get the 'Armoured Transport' heists on consoles. This is one of the earlier DLC's released on the Steam/PC version and will cost you £4.99. I purchased this on an Xbox 360 but I imagine it will also be on PS3. Also to use the Armoured Transport DLC you also need to download the free add-on 'Bain has got an update for us'. This will allow you to use the Armoured Transport DLC.